# python: <bound_named_property 'IKeithley2450MeasurementTrace.GetAverageReading' at 14280b4c448>

Tags: python

I'm trying to read some values from an instrument (keithly 2460) using ivi driver (ke2450_64.dll).

Here is the code:

```
import comtypes
from comtypes import client
KeithleyInstruments = client.GetModule('ke2450_64.dll') # load dll
SMU = client.CreateObject("Keithley2450.Keithley2450")
SMU.Initialize("USB0::0x05E6::0x2460::04455358::INSTR",False,False,'simulate = true')
SMU.Identity.InstrumentModel # identify the instrument model
SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading
```

Everything works fine, but running the last line, i.e. `SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading`, I get the response:

```
<bound_named_property 'IKeithley2450MeasurementTrace.GetAverageReading' at 14280b4c448>
```

Honestly, I do not understand what this means. How can I read the average reading from the instrument using the command `SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading`?
I know there are some ways using scpi commands, but the intention is to only use the ivi driver to perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to access an [optional property](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#properties-with-optional-arguments).

Try calling it like so `SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading()`.

Alternatively you can try `str(SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading)` to check whether it has a valid string representation attached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. already tried this, but got the following exception TypeError: required argument 'BufferName' missing

Comment: with str(SMU.Measurement.Trace.GetAverageReading), got the same message,
"<bound_named_property 'IKeithley2450MeasurementTrace.GetAverageReading' at 142924b1988>"

Comment: You will have to provide a buffername. Check the documentation to find out where the data from the instrument gets buffered. If there's no data, there's no average reading

Comment: Thanks for the tip, there was a command SMU.Measurement.Trace.CreateBuffer('test',1000) which create buffer. after this, if  we use the buffer name 'test', then it works.